Prefill modelform based on url
I'm struggling around Django form. I'm not really comfortable with this part of the framework.
Here is the case. I have a ModelForm containing a OneToOneField. I would like to prepopulated the ModelChoice Field with the object referenced in the URL. Ex: catalogue/location/add/7 to add a location to the product with pk=7
NB: if the PK is not included, the form is just not prefilled
models.py
class Product(models.Model):
   pass

class ProductLocation(geo_models.Model):
   product = geo_models.OneToOneField(Product, verbose_name=_('Product'), on_delete=geo_models.CASCADE, null=True,)
   geo_point = geo_models.PointField(verbose_name=_('Location'), blank=True)
   address = geo_models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Address'), max_length=255)

urls.py
urls += [
            re_path(r"^location/add/(?P<product_pk>\d+)/$",
                 self.add_update_location.as_view(),
                 name='catalogue-product-location-add'),  # Prepopulate product ModelChoiceField

            path("location/add",
                 self.add_update_location.as_view(),
                 name='catalogue-location-create'  # Empty product ModelChoiceField
                 ),

            path("location/<int:pk>",
                 self.add_update_location.as_view(),
                 name='catalogue-location-update')  # Edit an existing Location
        ]

views.py
class LocationCreateUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
    form_class = ProductLocationForm

    creating = True
    product = None

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        """
        Extend the role of get_object to retrieve the product specified in the url
        """
        self.creating = "pk" not in self.kwargs
        if self.creating:
            if self.kwargs.get("product_pk"):
                self.product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=self.kwargs["product_pk"])
            return None
        else:
            return super().get_object(queryset)

# Try this way
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        if self.product and not self.request.POST.get('product'):
            kwargs["product"] = self.product
        return kwargs

# Or this way
    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        if self.product:
            initial["product"] = self.product
        return initial

forms.py

class ProductLocationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, product=None, instance=None, *args, **kwargs):
        # I tried this
        if not instance and product:
            instance = ProductLocation(product=product)
        super().__init__(instance=instance, *args, **kwargs)

I tried to override get_initial() to pass the product to the form didn't validate, ask to select a product in the list and moreover, it erase the inital value.
I also use get_form_kwargs() to pass the product to the form init function and try to :

attach the product to the ProductLocation instance
set inital data in the init
set  self.fidels['product'].initial = product

Thanks for your help
PS : some references on SO

Pass initial value to a modelform in django
How to instantiate a Django ModelForm with pre-filled required fields?
Set initial value in django model form


Since you use an UpdateView, it will set the object, and use that as instance...

Well, the object is the ProductLocation. Location on a Product is not mandatory. Editing the Product is done on a different view/form/template. I've done this to simplify the code and avoid having two form with two object on the same page. Maybe I should reconsider the design.

The main reason this will not work is that an UpdateView indeed will trigger .get_object(…) [Django-doc] which will set the self.instance to the result of .get_object(…). This is not always wanted based on your use-case. We can make this optional by returning None in get_object() if no pk is part of the self.kwargs:
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


class LocationCreateUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
    model = ProductLocation
    form_class = ProductLocationForm

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        creating = self.creating = 'pk' not in self.kwargs
        if not creating:
            return super().get_object(queryset)

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        if 'product_pk' in self.kwargs:
            initial['product'] = get_object_or_404(
                Product, pk=self.kwargs['product_pk']
            )
        return initial
